# Webpack require.ensure(code splitting) with react component not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have the below component. It is not rendering the product module in the dom and also not showing any error in the console.

And if I use `ReactDOM.render(<ProductModule/>,document.getElementById('product-container'));` it is working.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class ProductModuleWrapper extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="product-container">
                {this.renderProductModules()}
            </div>
        );
    }

    renderProductModules() {
        require.ensure([],(require) => {
            var ProductModule =   require('../ProductModule').default;
            return ProductModule;
        },'productmodule');
    }
}
```

**edit :**

I think this is something to do with the async nature of the require ensure call, Please help

Comment: Does it render the product module if you return it from the `renderProductModules` function? At the moment you're not returning anything. `return require.ensure...`

Comment: Thank You, No but it will work if I wrap the 'QuickShopProductModule' in 'ReactDOM.render'  and render to some div, I found one difference btw normal component and dynamically loaded component which is the later doesn't have an owner property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React will only re-render if component's state or props have been updated. In your example, neither is so it won't render the component as it's fetched asynchronously.

I recommend that you use `this.state` as described in this blog post: http://blog.netgusto.com/asynchronous-reactjs-component-loading-with-webpack/